# How to parse e-mail bounce notifications

Tags: email, smtp, email-bounces, smtpd

What options do I have to parse the e-mails that have bounced? I am receiving the bounce notification from e-mail servers but don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you having trouble getting the bounce notification from your mailbox or are you having trouble parsing the e-mail once you have it?

Answer (score 2):

there is a bounce parsing library available for perl:

http://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::DeliveryStatus::BounceParser

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your setup but if you have access to your mail server , you can `pipe` these messages to a script on your server, which parses these emails and then you can take some decision based on that, for instance flag the email address as invalid or something in your database and not sending any more emails.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but maybe it can help others.

I couldn't find a solution so I made my own. It fetches the mails from an IMAP account and classifies them. It can post the resulting data to a remote http(s) endpoint or just to a simple csv file.

[» Bouncefetch](https://github.com/2called-chaos/bouncefetch)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of bouncefetch.