# How to parse Delivery Status Notifications emails bounced from Mailer Deamons

Tags: php, email, mailer

I'm trying to understand how to parse Delivery Status Notifications emails sent by Mailer Deamons when, for example, an email is sent to a non-existing mailbox or when to a full-of-space mailbox.

I had a look to the RFC3464 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3464.txt), and to those questions:

- [Detecting if an email is a "Delivery Status Notification" and extract information - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298285/detecting-if-an-email-is-a-delivery-status-notification-and-extract-informatio)
- [Retrieve bounce notification / report in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810581/retrieve-bounce-notification-report-in-php)
- [How to handle Delivery Status Notification of GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981298/how-to-handle-delivery-status-notification-of-gmail)
- [How to parse e-mail bounce notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447363/how-to-parse-e-mail-bounce-notifications)

What I can't understand is:

- Are **ALL** Mailer Deamons out there respecting RFC3464?
- I'm using PHP but I didn't really found a library to parse those emails; I think it's strange because I suppose that this is something not so new, I think others already had to do something like that in the past. Do you know some more resource I could take a look to?

How can I know all the possible errors that generate a bouncing email? How can I know ALL different formats of those emails so that I can write a proper parser?

What I need is:

- Know if an email I sent with PHPMailer (smtp) encountered an error didn't arrive to recipient;
- Know why.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, most deamons do not respect this RFC. When i've been faced to the problem, what i found out to be working the most is to check the content-type, it should contain `report-type=delivery-status`. You can also check the parts, on of them should have a content-type `message/delivery-status` and its header contain `action: failed`. But as said, doesn't work for all DSN. Let us know if you find any better way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. You already helped me a bit. I'll try to find out something more and test some bounced emails. I'll let you know.